# how to send a file from android to wifi printer programatically and print the file?

Tags: android, printing, wifi

I am developing a shopping cart application for Restaurants in Android 2.1 . I want to print the order details ( customer details , cart details, order total) , when user submit the order . I want to use some WIFI printer for printing the data. Please help me with suitable examples ...

Comment: have you seen this post http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19985/how-can-i-send-a-file-wirelessly-without-bluetooth-or-a-wi-fi-network-in-ics this may help you. they use WiFi-Direct option to do this

Comment: Hi @Anoop.. Did you find the solution for this question? Can you share your code for wifi printing and what printer you are using?

Comment: @Anoopka could you send how you resolved your problem with printer?

Comment: @Anoop - Did you find any solution for this question? Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The wireless printer you will be using generally provide SDKs or drivers along with their printers. So, its basically very easy to integrate in your application.
In my case I used: http://www.starmicronics.com/printer/home.aspx

2) To print your slips what you need to do is either convert your slips into bitmaps or bytes again depends upon the SDK's requirement like in what format they need information. So in this stage you will be converting your views/layouts in bitmaps.

This is the way I did and depends upon specific printer requirements. So, first understand what is your requirement.

There are printers supporting bluetooth profiles too. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I want to print the receipt for customer after ordering . I want the app to work on all WiFi printers ( all companies ). Please help me with suitable examples...

Comment: Hi abhy can you tell ,is Starmicronics support WiFi .

Comment: @Anoopka could you share your code which you got for wifi printer